# Is there a verify function in c standard libraries?

Tags: c, standard-library

Is there a `verify()` function (Such as [`VERIFY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcatwy09%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in msvc) or similar that is in the standard c libraries or do I have to write my own? If so, which header is it under?

**Edit:** The difference between assert and verify is that verify will still execute the function in a release build, whereas the statement in assert is not compiled in release.

I.e.

```
assert( printf("assert ") );

verify( printf("verify") );
```

in debug will print `"assert verify"` but in release will print `"verify"`.

Comment: It is entirely up to you whether asserts are enabled in your release build - this is controlled by the `NDEBUG` macro.

Comment: I see, the answer is no then, it's just a microsoft thing.

Comment: If you prefer doing things the Microsoft way then you can just compile with e.g. `gcc -DVERIFY=assert ...` but it's probably better to be portable and just use `assert` in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At runtime, C has the `assert` macro in `assert.h`.

At compile time, C (since C11) has the `static_assert` macro in `assert.h`.

For information, for `static_assert` some C89/C99 compilers also include it as a compiler extension. For example IAR compiler has the `static_assert` function in `intrinsics.h`.

Comment: Clarified my question, I am not looking for assert

Comment: @yuumei but `assert` works like `verify` from MS documentation. In C `assert` performs its job only when `NDEBUG` macro is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CUnit](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/) for unit testing. It is a C port of the good old JUnit library for Java.

Later edit: it seems there is a similar macro which I did not know about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the assert macro defined in assert.h